# Update operation in a model removes all the users stored in a many to many field in that model - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my app a student can send a teacher a follow request that gets accepted by the teacher and the student gets added to the teacher's follower list. The way I am storing the students as a follower for the teacher is by a many to many relationship model. Below is the code:

```
home_tuition_students = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='home_tuition_students')
    
general_tuition_students = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='general_tuition_students')
```

The above fields are inside a model that is actually the teacher's profile model where other information about the teachers are stored such as name, phone number, etc. Now I am facing a weird problem, whenever a teacher makes an update operation, e.g. change his phone no or any other detail, all the students stored in the many to many field get removed after updation. The update api looks like below:

```py
api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser, FormParser])     
def edit_teacher_detail(request):
  
   data = request.data
   
   if data is not None:
     
     queryset = TeacherDetail.objects.get(user = request.user)
     
     serializer = TeacherDetailSerializer(instance=queryset, data = data)
     
     try:
       if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
         return Response({'message':"details edited"} ,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       else:
         print(serializer._errors)
         return Response({'message': serializer._errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
     except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       return Response({"message": str(e)},status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
     
     
   
   else: 
      return Response({'message':'no query recieved'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I do not know how and why is it happening. Please suggest me a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was just playing with the code to figure out what was going wrong and found out that the problem was cause be the serializer that was being used. The serializer that was being used was serializing all the fields including the many to many field. I figured out that the serializer should only contain the fields that are allowed to be updated by the user else it will reset the field for which it did not receive any data.

I did not know that this should be done to use serializers while performing an update operation.